# KeyPressEvent without Focus

Tags: python, pyqt5, keypress

I am programming a simple GUI, that will open a opencv window at a specific point. This window has some very basic keyEvents to control it. I want to advance this with a few functions. Since my QtGui is my Controller, I thought doing it with the KeyPressedEvent is a good way. My Problem is, that I cannot fire the KeyEvent, if I am active on the opencv window.

So How do I fire the KeyEvent, if my Gui is out of Focus?

Do I really need to use GrabKeyboard?

The following code reproduces my Problem:

```py
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QWidget)
from PyQt5.Qt import Qt
import cv2


class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.first = True

    def openselect(self):
        im = cv2.imread(str('.\\images\\Steine\\0a5c8e512e.jpg'))
        self.r = cv2.selectROI("Image", im)

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        if event.key() == Qt.Key_Space and self.first:
            self.openselect()
            self.first = False
        print('Key Pressed!')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = MainWindow()

    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: This is my minimal: If I loose focus on my MainWindow, the keyPressEvent is not fired. If my Window is active and I press any button, the console prints. If not nothing happens.

Comment: Do not focus on the **minimum** since it is the most simple and trivial since it is only to erase code, you must focus on **reproducibility**. I point this out because in your post you talk about opencv but in your code I don't see any line of that.

Comment: You can reproduce my problem with this simple code. I mentioned opencv only, because it opens a second window, that I have to interact with. The Problem is not opencv related. So I didn't tagged opencv.

Comment: I have tested your code and I get "Key Pressed!" which is not what you indicate.

Comment: Yes shure I get also "Key Pressed!", but only if the QTWindow is in front. If I activate any other window (like browser, Anaconda, doesn't matter) any keypress results without the print.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The keyPressEvent method is only invoked if the widget has the focus so if the focus has another application then it will not be notified, so if you want to detect keyboard events then you must handle the OS libraries, but in python they already exist libraries that report those changes as [`pyinput`](https://github.com/moses-palmer/pynput)(`python -m pip install pyinput`):

```py
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets

from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener, KeyCode


class KeyMonitor(QtCore.QObject):
    keyPressed = QtCore.pyqtSignal(KeyCode)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.listener = Listener(on_release=self.on_release)

    def on_release(self, key):
        self.keyPressed.emit(key)

    def stop_monitoring(self):
        self.listener.stop()

    def start_monitoring(self):
        self.listener.start()


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    pass


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    monitor = KeyMonitor()
    monitor.keyPressed.connect(print)
    monitor.start_monitoring()

    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Hey, this is working as expected, thank you so far. I am confused about how to use the keyinput in other terms then just printing. In my example I want to switch the state of a checkbox inside a QMainwindow.

Comment: Okay figured out by myself. I loaded the monitor in my Mainwindow and and set itself as parent.